# Using node-adodb with .mdb Access Files

Tags: node.js, docker, ms-access, adodb

I am attempting to write a containerized Node application on Windows OS that intakes Microsoft Access databases and accesses the data within. I wish to use npm [node-adodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adodb) to interact with Access.

My application works perfectly fine with .accdb Access files. When I try to connect to .mdb Access files I get this error `Spawn C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error, Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed`. My code works on my local Windows computer, so I'm guessing that it's something to do with how my container environment is set up.

I set up the base Dockerfile like this:

```
# Get base Windows OS image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Set environment variables
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODEJS_VERSION 12.9.1

# Download & Install 2010 Access Driver
RUN powershell -Command "wget -Uri https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe -OutFile AccessDatabaseEngine.exe -UseBasicParsing"
RUN powershell -Command "Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath \"AccessDatabaseEngine.exe\""

# Download & Install 2016 Access Driver
RUN powershell -Command "wget -Uri https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe -OutFile accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe -UseBasicParsing"
RUN powershell -Command "Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath \"accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe\""

# Download and install Node.js
RUN powershell -Command "wget -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODEJS_VERSION%/node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-x64.msi -OutFile node.msi -UseBasicParsing"
RUN msiexec.exe /q /i node.msi

# Run node
CMD [ "node" ]
```

I establish the Access connection like so. How I instantiate the connection differs depending on if I'm in my local environment or online. It also differs on .accdb vs .mdb:

```
// Define connection string & initialize export connection depending on if it's a .accdb .mdb file
let access;
if ((file.path).substring(Math.max(0, (file.path).toString().length - 5)) === 'accdb') {
    const connStr = `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=${file.path};Persist Security Info=False;`;
    access = ADODB.open(connStr); // This works
} else {
    const connStr = `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=${file.path};`;
    access = ADODB.open(connStr); // This fails
}
```

Is there another software package that I need to install in order to work with .mdb files? Do I need to connect in a different way? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With the error message coming from "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe", please make sure that you have the 32-bit version of the "Microsoft Access Database Engine" distribution package installed.

If you have the 64-bit engine package installed, open the database connection like this:

```
access = ADODB.open(connStr, true);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for the help. I've tried this to no avail. In addition to alternating the boolean second parameter, I've also tried alternating between the 32bit and 64bit Access installations. I've even tried alternating between the 2010 and 2016 packages. No luck with any of this. I'm running out of ideas. If you think of anything else, I would be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: No problem. Have you tried to open the database in Access to find out its format?

Also, what error messages do you see when you try those different combinations?

Comment: By format I assume you mean it's db schema? If so, the format/schema is fine. The error messages stay the same regardless on if we have 2010 or 2016 installed, or if we installed the X32 version or the X64 version. If we instantiate the connection using X64 like your recommended, the error is `Spawn C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe error, Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed`. If we instantiate using X32, the error is what I originally reported, `Spawn C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error, Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed`.

Comment: I tried your JS code posted above. It works fine on my Windows 10 PC. I am out of ideas. :-(

Comment: The worst part is that it works on my Windows 10 PC as well. It works fine when I run it locally. The issue arises when I try to run the application in Windows Kubernetes. My Kubernetes OS pulls from the mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 Docker image, if that helps.
If no other ideas come to you, thank you for your time and assistance. If I figure this out, I'll be sure to post here.